How to correctly authorize certain fields using NestJS GraphQL?
I have a NestJS GraphQL API that has a User object I can query as such
@ObjectType()
export class User {
  @Field(() => ID)
  id: string

  @Field()
  name: string

  @Field()
  password: string
}

If the person making the request is authorized I want them to be able to retrieve the whole object, if not then just the password field should be excluded. Ideally I would want to use some sort of property on this object.
I have my own authorization system that I use for fine-grained permissions, however for the sake of this that is not important. I have tried adding the password field as a separate fieldResolver with a basic guard to check if the user is logged in:
 @UseGuards(UserGuard)
 @ResolveField(() => String)
 async password(@Parent() user: User): Promise<string> {
   return 'this is the password'
 }

If they are logged in it works as expected and I get this response:
{
  "id": "1",
  "name": "John Doe",
  "password": "this is the password"
}

However, if they're not logged in I get an Unauthorized error and the data is null:
{
  errors: [
    {
      "message": "Unauthorized",
      // more error stuff
    }
  ],
  data: null
}

What I would expect is that the password field is unauthorized, but the data for the other fields is still returned, e.g.
{
  errors: [
    {
      "message": "Unauthorized",
      "path": ["password"]
    }
  ],
  data: {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "John Doe"
  }
}

I know this is the behaviour in a .NET GraphQL API, so was wondering how you can implement this in NestJS? Or is this not desired behaviour?

I have created this public directive and field decorators
public.directive.ts
import { getDirective, MapperKind, mapSchema } from '@graphql-tools/utils';
import { ForbiddenException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { defaultFieldResolver, GraphQLSchema } from 'graphql';

export function publicDirectiveTransformer(schema: GraphQLSchema, directiveName: string) {
  const typeDirectiveArgumentMaps: Record<string, any> = {};
  return mapSchema(schema, {
    [MapperKind.OBJECT_TYPE]: (objectType) => {
      const publicDirective = getDirective(schema, objectType, directiveName)?.[0];
      if (publicDirective) {
        typeDirectiveArgumentMaps[objectType.name] = publicDirective;
      }
      return undefined;
    },
    [MapperKind.OBJECT_FIELD]: (fieldConfig, _fieldName, typeName) => {
      const publicDirective =
        getDirective(schema, fieldConfig, directiveName)?.[0] ??
        typeDirectiveArgumentMaps[typeName];
      const { resolve = defaultFieldResolver } = fieldConfig;
      fieldConfig.resolve = (source, args, context, info) => {
        if (context.user) return resolve(source, args, context, info);
        const { path } = info;
        // return to auth.guard for root level field query, mutation, subscription
        if (!path.prev) return resolve(source, args, context, info);
        // check fields for PublicProtected requests without token
        if (!publicDirective)
          throw new ForbiddenException({ message: `Can't access ${path.key}`, ctx: context });
        return resolve(source, args, context, info);
      };
      return fieldConfig;
    },
  });
}

public.decorator.ts
import { applyDecorators, SetMetadata } from '@nestjs/common';
import {
  Field,
  FieldOptions,
  ReturnTypeFunc,
  ResolveField,
  Directive,
  ObjectType,
  InterfaceType,
  InterfaceTypeOptions,
  ObjectTypeOptions,
} from '@nestjs/graphql';

export const PublicField = (returnTypeFunction?: ReturnTypeFunc, options?: FieldOptions) =>
  applyDecorators(Directive('@public'), Field(returnTypeFunction, options));

export const PublicResolveField = (
  name?: string,
  returnTypeFunction?: ReturnTypeFunc,
  options?: FieldOptions,
) => applyDecorators(Directive('@public'), ResolveField(name, returnTypeFunction, options));

export const PublicObjectType = (options?: ObjectTypeOptions) =>
  applyDecorators(Directive('@public'), ObjectType(options ?? {}));

export const PublicInterfaceType = (options?: InterfaceTypeOptions) =>
  applyDecorators(Directive('@public'), InterfaceType(options));

Include this app.module.ts
GraphQLModule.forRoot<ApolloDriverConfig>({
  ...Config options
  transformSchema: (schema) => publicDirectiveTransformer(schema, 'public'),
  buildSchemaOptions: {
    directives: [
      new GraphQLDirective({
        name: 'public',
        locations: [DirectiveLocation.FIELD_DEFINITION, DirectiveLocation.OBJECT],
      }),
    ],
  },
});

Now you can use like
@ObjectType()
export class User {
  @PublicField(() => ID)
  id: string

  @PublicField()
  name: string

  @Field()
  password: string
}

or you can also set entire class as public using @PublicObjectType or @PublicInterfaceType
NOTE: You need to set user key in GraphQL context if authorization is completed whose check is used in publicDirectiveTransformer
